# Comma-separated E-Mail ID validation via Regex in template in Angular 5?

Tags: regex, angular, html, typescript, angular5

I have a project in Angular 5. There is an input field for E-Mail ID(s). I wanted to achieve the following:

Allow the user to enter a maximum of 3 E-Mail ID(s), and obviously, each E-Mail ID would be validated. I was achieving this through:

1. Creating a function in my ts file: I was splitting the user input into comma separated values, and storing them in an array.
2. I was setting the max length of the array to 3, and validating each element of the array by iterating through it and was displaying the relevant error messages on the template according to the conditions.
3. The function was being called on (ngModelChange)

My old template code:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="mailingList">Mailing Lists ( Max 3 Email IDs ) </label>
    <input type="email" multiple class="form-control formgroup" placeholder="Enter Comma Separated Mailing Lists (Max 3)" [(ngModel)]="team.mailingList" name="mailingList" (ngModelChange)="validateMailingLists()" required>
    <p *ngIf="!emailValid" class="red">{{ errorMessage }} </p>
</div>
```

This is my old ts code:

```
const emailRegex = new RegExp(/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@]+)*)|(.+))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/);

validateMailingLists() {
    const sanitizedEmail = this.team.mailingList.replace(/,\s*$/, '').trim().split(',');
    this.emailValid = sanitizedEmail.every(email => emailRegex.test(email));
    if (this.emailValid === false) {
        this.errorMessage = 'Please enter valid E-Mail ID(s)';
    } 
    else if (sanitizedMailingList.length > 3) {
        this.emailValid = false;
      this.errorMessage = 'You can enter max 3 Email ID(s)';
    }
}
```

However, instead of creating a function and then calling it on `ngModelChange`, I was trying to do the validation on the template itself.

This is what I have tried so far:

New template code:

```
<label for="mailingList">Mailing Lists ( Max 3 Email IDs ) </label>
<span class="red">*</span>
<span class="red" *ngIf="mailingList.errors && (mailingList.touched || mailingList.dirty)">Invalid E-Mail ID(s) </span>
<input type="email" multiple class="form-control formgroup" placeholder="Enter Comma Separated Team Mailing List (Max 3)" [(ngModel)]="team.mailingList" name="mailingList" pattern="^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@]+)*)|(.+))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$" #mailingList="ngModel" mailingList required>
```

My questions are:

1. Could I split the user input into comma separated values via Regex in the template, and if yes, how?  The regex that I am using right now in the template only checks if the input is a valid E-Mail ID, but does not split the user input into comma separated values.
2. Also, how do I allow the user to enter only a maximum of 3 E-Mail ID(s) via Regex?

Earlier, it was achievable, via the split, trim and replace string functions.

I have searched a lot but have not found any solution for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex for validating 3 email address.

```
^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5}),?\s*){1,3}$
```

Note: `{1,3}` allows the user to enter up to 3 email ids.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following regex:

```
^(\s?[^\s,]+@[^\s,]+\.[^\s,]+\s?,)*(\s?[^\s,]+@[^\s,]+\.[^\s,]+)$
```

[Here](https://www.regextester.com/99193) you can verify regex.

Comment: This matches ##@$$.@@ as a valid email. Although the ideal regex for email is quite large but normally you should allow these characters in email [a-zA-Z0-9_.-]